# Jq variable add extra \

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq, backslash

Hi i have this bash code

```
#!/bin/bash
textb="\n 1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4"
jq  --arg textb "$textb" '. | {plain_text: (  $textb +  desc.envi )'
```

When i  run the comand  this giveme the next example

```
 #!/bin/bash
    \\n1 \\n2 \\n3 \\n4
```

Why jq add and extra "\"?  What i m going wrong?
I try some like this

```
textb="\n" 1 "\n" 2 "\n" 3 "\n" 4"
```

But i  have this result

```
n1 n2 n3 n4
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

`\n` does not mean linefeed/newline in a bash double quoted string. It's just backslash+lowercase n.

If you use linefeeds instead of backslashes and Ns, they will encode the way you want:

```
textb="
1
2
3
4"
jq -n --arg textb "$textb" '."the string is:" = $textb'
```

outputs:

```
{
  "the string is:": "\n1\n2\n3\n4"
}
```

Here are few other equivalent ways of putting literal linefeeds into a bash variable:

```
textb=$'\n1\n2\n3\n4'
textb=$(printf '\n%s' {1..4})
```